# Moving from Qt 4.7.4 to 4.8.0

Tags: qt, compilation, qt4.7

Well, i'm currently on 4.7.4, but i want to move to 4.8.0. But i heard that i need to compile it in order to use it. It is true? isn't there anyway to upgrade to 4.8.0 without compiling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to http://qt.nokia.com/downloads you will notice that there are precompiled binary installers. Compiling from source is an option. Make sure you practice your googles a bit too.